# How to implement Material chips in UITextfield using Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, ios12

[image: Like this image]I have needed this type of chips UITextfield with a cancel button

```
let chipView = MDCChipView()
chipView.titleLabel.text = "Furkan@vijapura.com"
chipView.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .selected)
chipView.sizeToFit()
chipView.backgroundColor(for: .selected)
self.view.addSubview(chipView)
self.userAdd.addSubview(chipView)
```

Comment: Did you get it to work? If so, could you answer this question, so I can refer it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a collectionView with multiple cells you can define the layout of each cell and your last cell will contain a text field.

Please let me know if you need a reference code for doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Supposing that you have installed via pods:

Text Field with Floating Placeholder

```
let textFieldFloating = MDCMultilineTextField()
scrollView.addSubview(textFieldFloating)

textFieldFloating.placeholder = "Full Name"
textFieldFloating.textView.delegate = self

textFieldControllerFloating = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: textFieldFloating) // Hold on as a property
```

Text Field with Character Count and Inline Placeholder

```
// First the text field component is setup just like a UITextField
let textFieldDefaultCharMax = MDCMultilineTextField()
scrollView.addSubview(textFieldDefaultCharMax)

textFieldDefaultCharMax.placeholder = "Enter up to 50 characters"
textFieldDefaultCharMax.textView.delegate = self

// Second the controller is created to manage the text field
textFieldControllerDefaultCharMax = MDCTextInputControllerUnderline(textInput: textFieldDefaultCharMax) // Hold on as a property
textFieldControllerDefaultCharMax.characterCountMax = 50
textFieldControllerDefaultCharMax.isFloatingEnabled = false
```

Also If you want to follow a Git Project Use: https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField

Comment: i need to iOS Material Chips text field like Tag